# Remove button from Edit mode in Materials dissapeared

Tags: materials, interface, groups

I dont know if im missing something but the remove button that appears in-between assign and select doesnt show anymore.

[image]

It might be something simple but i dont know what happened.

Comment: Am I crazy, or has there never been a remove button? I can't recall ever seeing something like that (though that shouldn't suggest I couldn't have missed something).

Comment: I'm the one feeling crazy, I used that remove button very frecuently and was there the entire time and all of the sudden disappears without me doing anything, and I tried to find out about what could have provoke it. but when i looked into it, it appears that no one has it (taking video tutorials for reference). And now feels like its like a Mandela effect.

Comment: Is there any chance you were using an addon that added extra buttons to the UI?

Comment: I dont recall using addons related to the interface, and theres nothing about it on the preferences tab.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno then. I'll admit - you've got me second guessing myself now, but I'm pretty sure I've never seen a remove button (and materials are one of my specialties).

Comment: I remember that it came handy when I had faces on a mesh that I didnt want them to be that specific material and just Select > Remove, but i dont know, i may be mixing it with the Remove button from the Vertex Groups tab.

Comment: You show the material list, there's no Remove button under the material list, you're confusing with the Vertex Groups list, no need for a Remove button in the material list, if you want to remove a material from a face, assign it to another material, even in 2.7 I don't see any Remove button

Comment: Well you could have an empty material slot and assign that to parts of mesh you don't want materials on. Though, in what context do you need parts of meshes with no materials?

Answer (score 0):

Basically to remove a material there are two standard ways:

1. Either press the minus button '-' to remove the material altogether. The first material in the material list will replace it automatically (if there is one). You can also remove all materials, but clicking the minus button, until there is no material left.
2. Or just apply the other material onto the faces by selecting it in the list & pressing assign.

PS: Funny little convo you guys are having in the comments XD . No there was no remove button in Blender, atleast not after 2.8. Before that, I cannot say. Nor have I heard of an addon, that adds that functionality, unless its a obscure one.